# How to change the relative point of a drawing (change the referencial)

Tags: c#, drawing

I'm drawing some functions, and so far I've been doing so using the standard `Graphics` in c#.

It happens that as usual he uses the top left corner as a referencial, and for the ones that already tried to plot a real-life graph using that corner, we know it's terrible, the Y axis is upside down, any scaling you might use just gets more complicated, etc.

I'd rather use the bottom left corner as a referencial, is this possible?

Comment: There are already a couple of answers for this one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030295/make-y-up-move-origin-c-sharp-system-drawing-graphics). Hope that helps.

Comment: Lol, and a pretty funny question too.. danke