# C# Windows Forms - Graphics - Plot X,Y Points, with +Y

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, graphics

This question has been partially answered ([Make +y UP, Move Origin C# System.Drawing.Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030295/make-y-up-move-origin-c-sharp-system-drawing-graphics)), I apologize if I haven't been able to find an easy solution on SO.

I need to plot X,Y graph points coming from a standard graph, where the origin (0,0) is in the center of the form, and +Y coordinates move in a vertical direction. See the attached image of a standard X, Y plot graph.

**How do I reconfigure the form, so that the origin (0,0) is in the center of form rather than top left, and +Y coordinates are plotted in a vertical fashion? Note: I'm really trying to do a polygon hit test, but within the standard X,Y plot graph where the origin is in the center, not top left like .Net Windows Forms.**   Here is what I would like:

1. Hit Test - I'm really trying to do a hit test here, not create a graph, so I don't think I can use a 3rd party graphing library.
2. Points - I will be using PointF points, I don't want to have to "flip" or transform the individual points, I would rather re-configure the form on form load
3. Windows Form setup - I would like a solution that reconfigures the form or container with something like ScaleTransform, rather than flipping Points as mentioned above
4. Windows Form size - I shouldn't need to know the pixel width of the form, at the time the form launches, this should be handled
5. Windows Form Resize - resizing isn't important to me it can be static after the app launches

Thank you the help,
Tim
[image]

Comment: Consider using an existing graphing library.  Unless you have very unique needs, you're probably much better off just grabbing a copy of ZedGraph than trying to do this yourself.

Comment: `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.ClientSize.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2);`  then draw your points.  Point 0, 0 will be in the middle.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer in the linked post doesn't actually show the use of TranslateTransform although this is the __key__!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw your graph, use TranslateTransform:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
  e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.ClientSize.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2);
  e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(-3, -3, 6, 6));
}
```

For hit testing, you can also use TranslateTransform along with a TransformPoints call:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
  using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics()) {
    g.TranslateTransform(this.ClientSize.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2);
    Point[] points = new Point[] { e.Location };
    g.TransformPoints(CoordinateSpace.World, CoordinateSpace.Device, points);
    MessageBox.Show(points[0].ToString());
  }      
}
```